# Deploy a node.js application (windows)

Tags: node.js

for a customer of mine i'm developing a node.js app.

I want to give him a simple setup program that handle the installation of node and relative modules in automatic without having to access the web.

Which is the best and efficient way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just give him the node.js installer und zip your app (with node_modules directory). He just has to install node.js and extract the zip file. You could write a .bat file which starts the app. That should be easy enough.

Comment: ehhhh ok. but Can I have also the node installation inside an automatic procedure?